# Discretization of nonlinear curvilinear dynamics equations

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, nonlinear-dynamics

I am considering a tracking model of the form
$$
\dot{x} = v\cos\psi\\
\dot{y} = v\sin\psi\\
\dot{v} = a\\
\dot{a} = 0\\
\dot{\psi} = \omega\\
\dot{\omega} = 0
$$
which is considering 2D position in $x$ and $y$, speed $v$ in direction $\psi$ from pos $x$ with turn rate $\omega$.

I am trying to discretize this. A similar model, assuming $a=0$, has been discretized in [doi.org/10.1109/cdc.1996.573612](http://doi.org/10.1109/cdc.1996.573612). In the paper it is proposed that
$$
x_{k+1} = x_{k} + \int_{t}^{t+T} v\cos\psi d\tau
$$
where if $\dot{v}=0$ then
$$
x_{k+1} = x_{k} + \frac{v}{\omega}\big(\sin(\omega(t+T)) - \sin(\omega t)\big)\\
\quad= x_{k} + \frac{2v}{\omega}\sin(\frac{\omega T}{2}) \cos(\psi + \frac{\omega T}{2})
$$
leveraging $\psi = \int \dot{\psi} dt = \int \omega dt = \omega t$.

I am trying to expand this in order to allow for a constant, but non-zero, $a$. So I set up the integral
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{k+1} &= x_{k} + \int_{t}^{t+T} v\cos\psi d\tau\\
&= x_{k} + \int_{y}^{t+T} v\cos(\omega\tau)d\tau
\end{aligned}
$$
I figured this can be solved using integration by parts, where
$$
u=v\\
du = a\\
d\nu=\cos(\omega\tau)d\tau\\
\nu = \frac{1}{\omega} \sin(\omega\tau)
$$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{y}^{t+T} v\cos(\omega\tau)d\tau &= \frac{v}{\omega}\sin(\omega\tau)\bigg|_{t}^{t+T} - \int_{t}^{t+T} \frac{a}{\omega}\sin(\omega\tau)d\tau\\
&= \frac{v|_{t+T}}{\omega}\sin(\omega(t+T)) - \frac{v|_{t}}{\omega}\sin(\omega t) + \frac{a}{\omega^{2}} \bigg(\cos(\omega(t+T)) - \cos(\omega t) \bigg)\\
&= 2\frac{v|_{t+T}-v|_{t}}{\omega} \sin(\frac{\omega T}{2}) \cos(\psi+\frac{\omega T}{2}) - \frac{2a}{\omega^{2}} \sin(\frac{\omega T}{2})\sin(\psi + \frac{\omega T}{2})
\end{aligned}
$$
I figure here that $v|_{t}$ is just $v$ and $v_{t+T}$ is $v+aT$? But I am in doubt if this is even a correct way to integrate this? As well I imagine there will be some numerical problems in evaluating $\frac{a}{\omega^{2}}$ for small turn rates. Is this a correct discretization of the original dynamics assuming that $a\neq 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you get
$$
x\rvert_{t+T}=x\rvert_t+\frac{(v\rvert_t+aT)\sin(\psi\rvert_t+\omega T)- v\rvert_t\sin(\psi\rvert_t)}{\omega}+\frac{a}{\omega^2}[\cos(\psi\rvert_t+\omega T)-\cos(\psi\rvert_t)]
$$
but you shouldn't compute it this way when $\lvert\omega\rvert$ is small.  Instead, we have
\begin{align*}\require{color}
x\rvert_{t+T}&=x\rvert_t
+\frac{v\rvert_t[\sin(\psi\rvert_t+\omega T)-\sin(\psi\rvert_t)]}{\omega}\\
&\hphantom{{}=x\rvert_t}
+\frac{a}\omega \frac{\omega T\sin(\psi\rvert_t+\omega T)+\cos(\psi\rvert_t+\omega T)-\cos(\psi\rvert_t)}{\omega}\\
&=x\rvert_t
+v\rvert_t T\cos(\psi\vert_t+\tfrac12\omega T)\operatorname{sinc}(\tfrac12\omega T)\\
&\hphantom{{}=x\rvert_t}
+\tfrac12 aT^2 \cos(\psi\rvert_t+\tfrac12\omega T)\operatorname{sinc}(\tfrac12\omega T)\\
&\hphantom{{}=x\rvert_t}
+\frac{aT}{\omega} 
\sin(\psi\rvert_t+\tfrac12\omega T)
\underbrace{\color{blue}[\cos(\tfrac12\omega T)-\operatorname{sinc}(\tfrac12\omega T)]}_{= -\frac1{12}\omega^2T^2+\frac1{480}\omega^4T^4+\dots }\\
&=x\rvert_t
+(v\rvert_t T+\tfrac12aT^2)\cos(\psi\vert_t+\tfrac12\omega T)\operatorname{sinc}(\tfrac12\omega T)\\
&\hphantom{{}=x\rvert_t}
-\tfrac1{12}{\color{red}(1-\tfrac1{40}\omega^2T^2+\dots)}a\omega T^3\sin(\psi\rvert_t+\tfrac12\omega T).
\end{align*}
The relative error of approximating the term in red by $\cos(\omega T/\sqrt{20})$ is approximately $(\omega T)^4/8400$ (or with $\operatorname{sinc}(\omega T\sqrt{3/20})$ is $(\omega T)^4/28000$), so should be small enough practically when $\omega T$ is small.

Comment: In addition, with respect to size, $\omega$ for me is likely, at most, less than 0.25. So I imagine this is fine, especially wrt sufficiently high sampling times.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you go from equality 1 to equality 2 in the derivation? To me it feels like there's a factor of 2 missing from using the identity $\sin(a)-\sin(b)=2\cos((a+b/2)\sin((a-b)/2)$. In addition I'm not quite sure I understand how the blue part appears from the former.

Comment: Yes, I skipped over a few steps.  Just apply the identity and similarly $\sin(\psi\vert_t+\omega T)=\sin((\psi\vert_t+\frac12\omega T)+\frac12\omega T)=\sin(\psi\vert_t+\frac12\omega T)\cos(\frac12\omega T)+\cos(\psi\vert_t+\frac12\omega T)\sin(\frac12\omega T)$.  Then use $\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\sin(x)/x$ to remove some $\omega$

Comment: Ah okay so it's just some trig identities I'm not familiar with, thanks for the explanation. I figure one can apply a similar approach to $\dot{y}=v\sin\psi$ but I figure I can do this myself following this as a guide. Also the substitution for the blue, where does this series come from?

Comment: Sorry to bother, but also where does the approximation for the red come from, do you have any text I can read regarding the series representation of the blue and the approximation of the red terms.

Comment: The series expansion of the blue term is just standard series for cosine and sine.  Then we take out a factor of $-\frac1{12}\omega^2T^2$ to get to the red series.  Approximating is just me fitting the $\cos(x)=1-\frac12 x^2+\frac1{24}x^4-\dots$ or $\operatorname{sinc}x=1-\frac16 x^2+\frac1{120}x^4-\dots$ to remove the $x^2$ term leaving a much smaller $x^4$ remainder.

Comment: How would you approach taking the jacobian of this, particularly wrt to $\omega$.